# How to pass parameters in empty object to get valid url

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, query-string, fetch

How to pass parameters in empty object to get valid url?

I'm using fetch method for geting API and getting url, but need to set query params to get finished url.

I need to pass *stationId* & *date* to *params* and set in *fetchtrips* function, now it's getting only type that is 'arrivals'.

```
 export default class Api {
  static fetch(type, params = {}) {
    const url = `${config.api.host}${config.api.paths[type]}`;
    console.log(url)
    let options = {
      headers: config.api.headers
    };

    Object.assign(options, params);

    return fetch(url, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
  }
  static fetchTrips(stationId, date) {
    const apiURL = Api.fetch('arrivals');
    return apiURL;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me you could do `Api.fetch('arrivals',{'stationId':stationId, 'date':date })`

Answer (score 0):

Try query-string node module to create query parameters.

import queryString from "query-string";

```
static fetch(type, params = {}) {
   const queryParam = queryString.stringify(param);
   const url = `${config.api.host}${config.api.paths[type]}${queryParam}`;
   let options = {
       headers: config.api.headers
   };
   return fetch(url, options)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
}
```